# Insert new array to php json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I tried to push a new array value to JSON

```
$var=array("code"=>"100");
$sql = SELECT order as orderID, pub as orderCode from cart
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($sql) {
$var[] = $row;
}
echo '{"status":'. json_encode($var).'}';
```

I want push this string to the JSON array above

```
$string = array("total"=>"3000");
```

and my script displays like this:

```
{  
"status":{  
   "code":"100",
      "0":{  
            "total":"3000"
          },
      "1":{  
            "orderID":"16",
            "orderCode":"14290290685322"
          },
      "2":{  
            "total":"3000"
          }
      }
   }
```

and I want var total inside like this:

```
**////////blablabla
   "1":{ 
      "orderID":"16",
      "orderCode":"14290290685322",
      "total":"3000" 
      }
*///blablba
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$var[] = array("total"=>"3000");` just before you encode to JSON

```
$var=array("code"=>"100");
$sql = SELECT order as orderID, pub as orderCode from cart
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($sql) {
  $row['total'] = '3000' ;
  $var[] = $row;
}
echo '{"status":'. json_encode($var).'}';
```

Comment: where i place  $string = array("total"=>"3000");

Comment: is okay, i'm need to push $string new element to JSON xD

Comment: it display error like this Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Comment: that same exactly what i did tehehe but still getting display total separated from JSON ROW

Comment: nah, absolutely right (y). thank you very much for help me xD